# Don't understand these ModuleNotFound errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am a beginner and learning Python. I have setup the environment with SublimeText and Python3.x

I am fine in creating code on Sublime and building it locally through Ctrl+B and for `input()` function I installed SublimeREPL and it works find up till now.

The issue I am facing is on Python interpreter. I am facing below error while import any package:

```
import tweepy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

I cannot even run a Python script from there. My Python path is below:

```
C:\Users\waqas.FVC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
```

`Demo.py` and `hello.py` are the two scripts I wrote initially which I am trying to execute from Python Terminal, but it is showing below errors:

```
test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Demo.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Demo' is not defined
```

Comment: `pip install tweepy`?

Comment: Are you sure you have tweepy installed? Did you use `pip install`, `conda install`, or something else? Also, you run python scripts that way through your terminal/command prompt, not your python interpreter

Comment: If the two scripts you wrote are in the current directory, you should be able to run them from within the Python console by typing `import test` and/or `import demo`. To run them from the Windows `cmd` command-line prompt, you will need to type in something similar to `python test.py` to execute one of them.

Comment: I used pip install tweepy. I don't know the reason but now its working from Windows cmd from the Python directory path just by typing demo.py

Answer (score 1):

The initial Python download includes a number of libraries, but there are many, many more that must be downloaded and installed separately.  Tweepy is among those libraries.

You can find, and download, tweepy from  here:

https://pypi.org/project/tweepy/